# Latex Table goes out of margins

Tags: latex

I have the following code which worked in my previous latex template, but now I have to submit to a journal and the tables goes out of the margin. I tried to use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% ...}` it does work. I have attached the code below for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[b5j,hmargin={1 in,0.6 in},vmargin={1 in,0.6 in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[labelsep=space, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Parameter estimates }
\label{tab:Application_MOTLOBXL1}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccccc}
\hline
Distribution & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Estimates} & -2Log(L) & AIC   & AICC  & BIC   & $W^{*}$ & $A^{*}$ & K-S    &  P-value & SS \\ \hline
MOTLOBX-L       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\  2.62$\times 10^{-3}$\\ (8.33$\times 10^{-4}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 1.21$\times 10^{1}$\\ (2.94$\times 10^{-4}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\  1.06$\times 10^{3}$\\ (1.41$\times 10^{-9}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 1.13\\ (5.42$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}  & 24.4  & 32.4 & 33.1 & 41.0 & 0.0639 & 0.3929  & 0.0891 & 0.6998 &  0.0581          \\ \hline
MOTLOBX-W         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 5.71$\times 10^{-3}$\\ (2.01$\times 10^{-3}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 8.45$\times 10^{1}$\\ (6.09$\times 10^{-6}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\ 8.12$\times 10^{2}$\\ (1.28$\times 10^{-8}$)\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\lambda$\\ 3.61$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (2.07$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}  & 25.1  & 33.1 & 33.8 & 41.7 & 0.1076  & 0.6042 & 0.0971 &  0.5928 &  0.0840                    \\ \hline
WL          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$a$\\ 3.29$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (6.38$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$b$\\ 3.97\\ (3.85$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 7.24$\times 10^{3}$\\ (6.30$\times 10^{-5}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 1.41$\times 10^{4}$\\ (3.25$\times 10^{-5}$)\end{tabular}    & 29.1 & 37.1 & 37.8 & 45.6 &  0.1962 & 1.0892  & 0.1425 & 0.1544 & 0.1813\\ \hline
GBXII          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$a$\\ 3.01$\times 10^{-2}$\\ (3.27$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$b$\\ 1.42\\ (5.97$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$c$\\ 1.57\\ (5.42$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 3.22\\ (1.87)\end{tabular}    & 28.0 & 36.0 & 36.7 & 44.6 &  0.1616 & 0.9076  & 0.1318 & 0.2240 & 0.1504\\ \hline
MOOBII-Lo         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\ 4.51$\times 10^{2}$\\ (4.34$\times 10^{-6}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 1.96\\ (1.71$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 9.20$\times 10^{-2}$\\ (4.17$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\lambda$\\ 4.45\\ (7.51$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}    & 40.4 & 48.4 & 49.1 & 57.0 &  0.3724 & 2.0787  & 0.1412 & 0.1619 & 0.2428\\ \hline
MOOBII-L         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\ 7.08$\times 10^{2}$\\ (1.74$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 1.07$\times 10^{2}$\\ (3.24$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 1.14$\times 10^{1}$\\ (1.14$\times 10^{1}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\lambda$\\ 1.84$\times 10^{1}$\\ (1.89)\end{tabular}    & 32.0 & 40.0 & 40.7 & 48.6 &  0.2639 & 1.4517  & 0.1257 & 0.2727 & 0.1704\\ \hline
TLOBX-L           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 3.17$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (1.56$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 1.99$\times 10^{1}$\\ (8.88)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 9.13$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (6.17$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} - \end{tabular}  & 42.3  & 48.3 & 48.7 & 54.7 & 0.4676  & 2.5657  & 0.2280 & 0.0029 & 0.6164                     \\ \hline
TL-L           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 4.22$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (2.96$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 9.53\\ (5.85)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 3.53\\ (3.85$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} - \end{tabular}  & 62.6  & 68.6 & 69.0 & 75.0 & 0.6755 & 3.6946  & 0.3781 & $<0.0001$ & 2.4809                    \\ \hline
MO-L           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\ 2.85$\times 10^{1}$\\ (1.27$\times 10^{1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 7.92\\ (8.73$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}-\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} - \end{tabular}  & 45.6  & 49.6 & 49.8 & 53.9 & 0.4969 & 2.7489  & 0.1537 & 0.1019
 & 0.3005                     \\ \hline
OBX-L           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 5.83\\ (7.73$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 1.03\\ (6.09$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}-\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} - \end{tabular}  & 45.6  & 51.7 & 51.9 & 56.0 &  0.5629 & 3.0915  & 0.2313 & 0.0024 & 0.6509                     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have already submitted but I'd have a few improvements for you. Mostly, I changed to slightly better rules, formatted numbers and added extra vertical spaces for better presentation (also see the comments in the code)

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[b5j,hmargin={1 in,0.6 in},vmargin={1 in,0.6 in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{rotating}
    % sidwaystable environment does not rotate pages when viewing PDFs
    % In twoside documents and no option is given to the package,
    % sidewaystable rotates table such that bottom edge is facing outer margin.
    %    figuresright - bottom edge always turned to the right
    %    figureleft   - bottom edge always turned to the left
\usepackage{booktabs}  % improved rules
\usepackage{siunitx}   % S type column to formnat numbers

\captionsetup[table]{
  skip=3pt,
  position=top,
  labelsep=space,
  labelfont=bf,
}
\sisetup{
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=2,
  table-format=1.2,
}

\newcommand\mlrule{\midrule[\cmidrulewidth]}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.05}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{-3pt}
  \small
  \centering
  \caption{Parameter estimates}\label{tab:Application_MOTLOBXL1}
  \begin{tabular}{l *8{c} *5{S}}
    \toprule\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{13pt}
    Distribution & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Estimates} & -2Log(L) & AIC & AICC & BIC & {$W^{*}$} & {$A^{*}$} & {K-S} & {P-value} & {SS} \\ \midrule
    MOTLOBX-L
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\alpha$             \\
        2.62$\times 10^{-3}$\\
        (8.33$\times 10^{-4}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\theta$            \\
        1.21$\times 10^{1}$ \\
        (2.94$\times 10^{-4}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\delta$            \\
        1.06$\times 10^{3}$ \\
        (1.41$\times 10^{-9}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\beta$ \\
        1.13 \\
        (5.42$\times 10^{-2}$)
    \end{tabular} & 24.4 & 32.4 & 33.1 & 41.0 & 0.0639 & 0.3929 & 0.0891 & 0.6998 & 0.0581 \\ \mlrule
    MOTLOBX-W
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\alpha$             \\
        5.71$\times 10^{-3}$ \\
        (2.01$\times 10^{-3}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\theta$            \\
        8.45$\times 10^{1}$ \\
        (6.09$\times 10^{-6}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\delta$            \\
        8.12$\times 10^{2}$ \\
        (1.28$\times 10^{-8}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\lambda$            \\
        3.61$\times 10^{-1}$ \\
        (2.07$\times 10^{-2}$)
    \end{tabular} & 25.1 & 33.1 & 33.8 & 41.7 & 0.1076 & 0.6042 & 0.0971 & 0.5928 & 0.0840 \\ \mlrule
    WL
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $a$                  \\
        3.29$\times 10^{-1}$ \\
        (6.38$\times 10^{-2}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $b$  \\
        3.97 \\
        (3.85$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\alpha$            \\
        7.24$\times 10^{3}$ \\
        (6.30$\times 10^{-5}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\beta$             \\
        1.41$\times 10^{4}$ \\
        (3.25$\times 10^{-5}$)
    \end{tabular} & 29.1 & 37.1 & 37.8 & 45.6 & 0.1962 & 1.0892 & 0.1425 & 0.1544 & 0.1813 \\ \mlrule
    GBXII
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $a$                  \\
        3.01$\times 10^{-2}$ \\
        (3.27$\times 10^{-2}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $b$  \\
        1.42 \\
        (5.97$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $c$  \\
        1.57 \\
        (5.42$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\theta$ \\
        3.22 \\
        (1.87)
    \end{tabular} & 28.0 & 36.0 & 36.7 & 44.6 & 0.1616 & 0.9076 & 0.1318 & 0.2240 & 0.1504 \\ \mlrule
    MOOBII-Lo
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\delta$            \\
        4.51$\times 10^{2}$ \\
        (4.34$\times 10^{-6}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\alpha$ \\
        1.96 \\
        (1.71$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\beta$              \\
        9.20$\times 10^{-2}$ \\
        (4.17$\times 10^{-2}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\lambda$ \\
        4.45 \\
        (7.51$\times 10^{-2}$)
    \end{tabular} & 40.4 & 48.4 & 49.1 & 57.0 & 0.3724 & 2.0787 & 0.1412 & 0.1619 & 0.2428 \\ \mlrule
    MOOBII-L
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\delta$            \\
        7.08$\times 10^{2}$ \\
        (1.74$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\alpha$            \\
        1.07$\times 10^{2}$ \\
        (3.24$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\beta$             \\
        1.14$\times 10^{1}$ \\
        (1.14$\times 10^{1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\lambda$           \\
        1.84$\times 10^{1}$ \\
        (1.89)
    \end{tabular} & 32.0 & 40.0 & 40.7 & 48.6 & 0.2639 & 1.4517 & 0.1257 & 0.2727 & 0.1704 \\ \mlrule
    TLOBX-L
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\alpha$             \\
        3.17$\times 10^{-1}$ \\
        (1.56$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\theta$            \\
        1.99$\times 10^{1}$ \\
        (8.88)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\beta$              \\
        9.13$\times 10^{-1}$ \\
        (6.17$\times 10^{-2}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & -- & 42.3 & 48.3 & 48.7 & 54.7 & 0.4676 & 2.5657 & 0.2280 & 0.0029$^{**}$ & 0.6164 \\ \mlrule
    TL-L
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\alpha$             \\
        4.22$\times 10^{-1}$ \\
        (2.96$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\theta$ \\
        9.53 \\
        (5.85)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\beta$ \\
        3.53 \\
        (3.85$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & -- & 62.6 & 68.6 & 69.0 & 75.0 & 0.6755 & 3.6946 & 0.3781 & 0.0001$^{*}$ & 2.4809 \\ \mlrule
    MO-L
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\delta$            \\
        2.85$\times 10^{1}$ \\
        (1.27$\times 10^{1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\beta$ \\
        7.92 \\
        (8.73$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & -- & -- & 45.6 & 49.6 & 49.8 & 53.9 & 0.4969 & 2.7489 & 0.1537 & 0.1019
    & 0.3005  \\
    \mlrule
    OBX-L
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\theta$ \\
        5.83 \\
        (7.73$\times 10^{-1}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
        $\beta$ \\
        1.03 \\
        (6.09$\times 10^{-2}$)
    \end{tabular}
    & -- & -- & 45.6 & 51.7 & 51.9 & 56.0 & 0.5629 & 3.0915 & 0.2313 & 0.0024$^{**}$ & 0.6509 \\ \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{14}{@{}l}{$^{*}$p-value $<0.0001$, \qquad$^{**}$p-value $<0.005$}
  \end{tabular}%
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a (bit) smaller font and place this table on a landscape page:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[b5j,hmargin={1 in,0.6 in},vmargin={1 in,0.6 in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[labelsep=space, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym}

\usepackage{lscape}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Parameter estimates }
\label{tab:Application_MOTLOBXL1}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccccc}
\hline
Distribution & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Estimates} & -2Log(L) & AIC   & AICC  & BIC   & $W^{*}$ & $A^{*}$ & K-S    &  P-value & SS \\ \hline
MOTLOBX-L       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\  2.62$\times 10^{-3}$\\ (8.33$\times 10^{-4}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 1.21$\times 10^{1}$\\ (2.94$\times 10^{-4}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\  1.06$\times 10^{3}$\\ (1.41$\times 10^{-9}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 1.13\\ (5.42$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}  & 24.4  & 32.4 & 33.1 & 41.0 & 0.0639 & 0.3929  & 0.0891 & 0.6998 &  0.0581          \\ \hline
MOTLOBX-W         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 5.71$\times 10^{-3}$\\ (2.01$\times 10^{-3}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 8.45$\times 10^{1}$\\ (6.09$\times 10^{-6}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\ 8.12$\times 10^{2}$\\ (1.28$\times 10^{-8}$)\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\lambda$\\ 3.61$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (2.07$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}  & 25.1  & 33.1 & 33.8 & 41.7 & 0.1076  & 0.6042 & 0.0971 &  0.5928 &  0.0840                    \\ \hline
WL          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$a$\\ 3.29$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (6.38$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$b$\\ 3.97\\ (3.85$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 7.24$\times 10^{3}$\\ (6.30$\times 10^{-5}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 1.41$\times 10^{4}$\\ (3.25$\times 10^{-5}$)\end{tabular}    & 29.1 & 37.1 & 37.8 & 45.6 &  0.1962 & 1.0892  & 0.1425 & 0.1544 & 0.1813\\ \hline
GBXII          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$a$\\ 3.01$\times 10^{-2}$\\ (3.27$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$b$\\ 1.42\\ (5.97$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$c$\\ 1.57\\ (5.42$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 3.22\\ (1.87)\end{tabular}    & 28.0 & 36.0 & 36.7 & 44.6 &  0.1616 & 0.9076  & 0.1318 & 0.2240 & 0.1504\\ \hline
MOOBII-Lo         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\ 4.51$\times 10^{2}$\\ (4.34$\times 10^{-6}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 1.96\\ (1.71$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 9.20$\times 10^{-2}$\\ (4.17$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\lambda$\\ 4.45\\ (7.51$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}    & 40.4 & 48.4 & 49.1 & 57.0 &  0.3724 & 2.0787  & 0.1412 & 0.1619 & 0.2428\\ \hline
MOOBII-L         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\ 7.08$\times 10^{2}$\\ (1.74$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 1.07$\times 10^{2}$\\ (3.24$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 1.14$\times 10^{1}$\\ (1.14$\times 10^{1}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\lambda$\\ 1.84$\times 10^{1}$\\ (1.89)\end{tabular}    & 32.0 & 40.0 & 40.7 & 48.6 &  0.2639 & 1.4517  & 0.1257 & 0.2727 & 0.1704\\ \hline
TLOBX-L           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 3.17$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (1.56$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 1.99$\times 10^{1}$\\ (8.88)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 9.13$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (6.17$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} - \end{tabular}  & 42.3  & 48.3 & 48.7 & 54.7 & 0.4676  & 2.5657  & 0.2280 & 0.0029 & 0.6164                     \\ \hline
TL-L           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\alpha$\\ 4.22$\times 10^{-1}$\\ (2.96$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 9.53\\ (5.85)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 3.53\\ (3.85$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} - \end{tabular}  & 62.6  & 68.6 & 69.0 & 75.0 & 0.6755 & 3.6946  & 0.3781 & $<0.0001$ & 2.4809                    \\ \hline
MO-L           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\delta$\\ 2.85$\times 10^{1}$\\ (1.27$\times 10^{1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 7.92\\ (8.73$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}-\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} - \end{tabular}  & 45.6  & 49.6 & 49.8 & 53.9 & 0.4969 & 2.7489  & 0.1537 & 0.1019
 & 0.3005                     \\ \hline
OBX-L           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\theta$\\ 5.83\\ (7.73$\times 10^{-1}$)\end{tabular}          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\beta$\\ 1.03\\ (6.09$\times 10^{-2}$)\end{tabular}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}-\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} - \end{tabular}  & 45.6  & 51.7 & 51.9 & 56.0 &  0.5629 & 3.0915  & 0.2313 & 0.0024 & 0.6509                     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

I find it a bit difficult to make good looking tables in LaTeX, so I usually use this site: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/.
It lets you create your table and then it spits out the LaTeX code.
I hope you can use it.